# Undefined index: value in _webform_conditional_get_all_components()

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'm getting an error on the webform

Here is the error:

Notice: Undefined index: value in _webform_conditional_get_all_components() (line 662 of /home3/site/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_conditional/webform_conditional.module).

I'm using Drupal 7 and the latest version of Webform.

I also have the error notification off.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you have webform_conditional module installed even though conditionals are part of webform module?

☝️This is the answer. If webform_conditional module is uninstalled properly it simply is impossible for that module to still be throwing error messages.

Comment: In a matter of fact, I do have it installed. Should I deactivate it to make it inactive?

Comment: Yes - it has been part of webform module itself for a very long time.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot. Can it be causing other issues as well?

Comment: Still having the same issues.

Comment: You’re saying you’ve uninstalled webform_conditional module but you’re still getting that error message? That’s not possible.